# Bootstrap DateTimepicker doesn't show value (.NET MVC 5)

Tags: eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use DateTimePicker to just pick a time. Everything works pretty well the first time. I can choose a time, that time is sent to the controller and stored in the database. However, if I try to set the value of the text box, nothing shows even though, the value is there. My set up is pretty simple, here's the input box (.NET Razor)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MondayStart, new { @class = "form-control timepicker", autocomplete = "off" })
```

My script:

```
        $('.timepicker').data("DateTimePicker").options({
            showClose: true,
            showClear: true,
            format:'LT'
        });
```

And when I inspect the rendered textbox, here's what shows:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control timepicker" id="MondayStart" name="MondayStart" type="text" value="3:00 PM">
```

Notice the value is set. Any idea why the box is blank and doesn't display 3:00 PM?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

:: Tom

Comment: you need to call $('.timepicker').datetimepicker() first

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue seems to be I was only passing the time as a value. Once I appended a date and passed date and time, it shows up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution and it works for me:

Just add the DateTime value in your Razor HtmlHelper attr.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MondayStart, new {
    @class = "form-control timepicker",
    @Value = Model.MondayStart.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy"), autocomplete = "off"
}).
```